# File pointer will not initialize in a separate function (seg fault on fclose)

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, fclose

kk. i need to understand life.
when i pass fp, a File pointer, into a new function, and open it there, fclose(fp) causes a seg fault! and i discovered that the file pointer, fp, was never opened.

```
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   File *fp;
   //*argv == filename
   functionToOpenFile(fp,*argv);
   //do stuff
   fclose(fp);
}

functionToOpenFile(File *fp, char *filename)
{
   fp = fopen(filename,"w");
   //error handling not shown
}
```

my solution, which works, is to pass in the address of fp, which is a pointer to a pointer to a File. i dont understand why it changes things

```
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   File *fp;
   //*argv == filename
   functionToOpenFile(&fp,*argv);
   //do stuff
   fclose(fp);
}

functionToOpenFile(File **fp, char *filename)
{
   *fp = fopen(filename,"w");
   //error handling not shown
}
```

-AUstin

Answer (score 3):

Because you are sending a pointer as a parameter, which means it will be created on stack, so the changes you make in your function cannot be seen outside the scope of the function. So when you want to close the file, you are actually trying to close something you didnot open before.

Answer (score 2):

You are not changing the passed pointer, you're only changing your local copy of it. So naturally at the end of the function **for the caller it looks as if `functionToOpenFile` did nothing**. Try this:

```
functionToOpenFile(FILE **fp, char *filename)
{
   *fp = fopen(filename,"w");
}

/* ... */
functionToOpenFile(&fp,*argv);
```

There is a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html) describing this exact problem.

Comment: of course! i have to dereference any pointer if i want to modify the data in my calling function

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   FILE *fp;
   //*argv == filename
   fp = functionToOpenFile(argv[1]); // better than argv[0] aka *argv.
   if (fp) {
        //do stuff
        fclose(fp);
   } else {
       // error occurred, but has already been dealt with.
   }
}

FILE * functionToOpenFile(char *filename)
{
   FILE * fp = fopen(filename,"w");
   //error handling not shown
   return fp;
}
```

Comment: Err code is kind of messed up... Shouldn't `FILE * functionToOpenFile(char *filename)` be `FILE * functionToOpenFile(FILE **fp, char *filename)` & `*fp = fopen(..)` ? Maybe return type can be changed as well?